# iOS layout: push UIView below automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiview

I have a view with multiple subviews (UIView, UIButton, UIImage). For example: If I tap on a button, a UIView will expand its frame, and I really want all the components below this UIView will be relocated below this view.

Is there anyone have this problem before? Is there any good approach rather than relocating all subviews by code?

Thanks

Comment: provide more context with real scenario... will be better to understand us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use autolayout and constraints. Set height constraint on the UIView that expand its frame and vertical space constraints on other subviews. Change the constant value of the height constraint and the other subviews will move respecting space constraints.

Comment: Thanks, I found it. The good solution is using constraints for those subviews.

Answer (score 0):

U can use `autoresizingMask` property for your subViews.
Example:

```
myButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

And when you expand your content UIView's frame, this button keeps it's position at the bottom of it's ContentView automatically. You don't need to change the myButton's frame.